# Gunzip -c to dir other than /boot

Tags: unix, gunzip

I am trying to gunzip -c a file and I am getting the following error

`gzip: stdout: No space left on device`

From what I can find online it seems that my /boot directory doesn't have enough space but is there a way to specify the location that the temporary file is written to instead of defaulting to /boot

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't usually use the /boot directory. What is the full command you are using?

Comment: ```gunzip -c FILENAME``` returns the following error ```gzip: stdout: No space left on device```